# Javascript. Перенос любых предлогов в абзацах от 1 до 3х символов. Висячие предлоги. regex

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить regexp.
Есть неограниченное количество абзацев со случайным текстом на русском или английском (A-zА-я).
Все предлоги (1-3 символа) с пробелом заменяем на предлог+`&nbsp`;

```
$('p').each(function() {
  $(this).val().replace(...);
});
```

Comment: Вы уверены что хотите делать это регуляркой? В 1-3 символа кроме предлогов попадают местоимения,, союзы, междометия и даже некоторые существительные с глаголами (не бей бак), если вам нужно переносить именно предлоги - лучше их явно перечислить

Comment: Дизайнеры всё это переносят. Плюс нужно универсальное решение на все языки (русский, английский, эстонский, марсианский).

Comment: Вам @Darth о другом хотел сказать, но если вы уверены в том, что делаете, то такой вариант:  `.replace(/(?<=^|\s)[\p{L}]{1,3}(?=\s)/gu, '$&&nbsp;'))`. P.S. Чтобы получить текстовое содержимое, в jQuery используют метод `.text()`, а не `val()`

Comment: Согласен с @Darth есть куча предлогов длиннее 3-х символов, после которых надо ставить *неразрывный пробел* по правилам русской типографики: «перед», «чтобы», «через» и т.д. И их лучше уточнить в вашей регулярке. А ещё, если уж на то пошло, *неразрывный пробел* ставятся так же *перед* единицами измерения, вокруг тире и сокращений и перед последним словом предложения, чтобы не «висело». Посмотрите, например, как сделан [типограф.js](https://github.com/BufferOverflowx86/JSTypography/blob/master/jstypograph.js)

Comment: Вы можете перечислить все предлоги на эстонском или испанском?

Comment: Я просто сам устал биться с дизайнерами. Цитирую. "Всё что до 3х символов не оставлляем в конце строки."

Comment: @Deonis не сработала регулярка
  $('p').each(function() {
    $(this).text().replace(/(?<=^|\s)[\p{L}]{1,3}(?=\s)/gu, '$&&nbsp;');
  });

Comment: А как вы определили, если результат никуда не выводится? )) Держите: `$('p').each(function() {
   $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/(?<=^|\s)[\p{L}]{1,3}(?=\s)/gu, '$&&nbsp;'));
 });`

Comment: @Deonis спасибо, но пробелы после &nbsp; остаются.

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/rD6IUsLoj4rtUA

Comment: Теги <br> почему-то удаляются из абзацев (

Comment: Итог:
  $('.teamblock p').each(function() {
    st = $(this).html();
    st = st.replace(/(?<=^|\s)[\p{L}]{1,3}(?=\s)/gu, '$&&nbsp;')
    st = st.replaceAll('&nbsp; ', '&nbsp;');
    $(this).html(st);
  });

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.teamblock p').each(function() {
  st = $(this).html();
  st = st.replace(/(?<=^|\s)[\p{L}]{1,3}(?=\s)/gu, '$&&nbsp;')
  st = st.replaceAll('&nbsp; ', '&nbsp;');
  $(this).html(st);
});
```

```css
.teamblock {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="teamblock">
  <p>Помогите составить regexp. Есть неограниченное количество абзацев со случайным текстом на русском или английском (A-zА-я). Все предлоги (1-3 символа) с пробелом заменяем на предлог+&amp;nbsp;</p>
  <p>Я просто сам устал биться с дизайнерами. Цитирую. "Всё что до 3х символов не оставлляем в конце строки."</p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```